# How to use a case statement to exclude multiple values from a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting some values from a sheet that I am displaying in a listbox, as you can in the top part of the screenshot (rooms)

[image]

I am using the following code

```
ElseIf Left(sh.Cells(r, 8), 1) = "Y" Then ' <<< display all rooms that are working      
        .AddItem
        .List(lC, 0) = sh.Cells(r, 1)
        .List(lC, 1) = sh.Cells(r, 2)
        .List(lC, 2) = sh.Cells(r, 3)
        .List(lC, 3) = sh.Cells(r, 4)
        .List(lC, 4) = sh.Cells(r, 5)
        .List(lC, 5) = sh.Cells(r, 6)
        .List(lC, 6) = sh.Cells(r, 7)
        .List(lC, 7) = sh.Cells(r, 8)

        lC = lC + 1
    End Select          
End If
```

However, I am using another piece of code that gets rooms that are already in use (in the bottom part of the screenshot), in the list box.

What I am trying to do is exclude these room numbers (4,7,6,2,1) from the rooms at the top listbox (rooms)

My idea was to put them in a variable, with quotes and commas e.g.

```
roomsInUse = roomsInUse & Chr(34) & sh1.Cells(row, 23) & Chr(34) & ", "
```

then remove the trailing comma

```
roomsinuseformatted = Left(roomsInUse, Len(roomsInUse) - 2)
```

Then use a case on my code above to exclude these room numbers from showing e.g.

```
ElseIf Left(sh.Cells(r, 8), 1) = "Y" Then ' <<< display all rooms that are working
    Select Case sh.Cells(r, 1)
    Case roomsinuseformatted 
      Me.lstRooms.AddItem "No Interviews"
      MsgBox ("test")
    Case Else
    'MsgBox (UsedRooms)

        .AddItem
        .List(lC, 0) = sh.Cells(r, 1)
        .List(lC, 1) = sh.Cells(r, 2)
        .List(lC, 2) = sh.Cells(r, 3)
        .List(lC, 3) = sh.Cells(r, 4)
        .List(lC, 4) = sh.Cells(r, 5)
        .List(lC, 5) = sh.Cells(r, 6)
        .List(lC, 6) = sh.Cells(r, 7)
        .List(lC, 7) = sh.Cells(r, 8)

        lC = lC + 1
    End Select   
End If
```

... but this doesn't work, I know this looks sloppy, and I am sure there is a better way to do it - but wasn't sure?

P.S. `Select Case sh.Cells(r, 1)` is the room number from the first listbox in the screenshot.

full pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QpTKR4V4

Comment: BTW - looks like you're missing a bit of code from your first ElseIf code block (the Select beginning)

Comment: I have the full code, I can paste it but I don't know if it will be confusing as only this else if has the main bit I am having problems with?, I'll do a pastebin

Comment: Create a `scripting.dictionary`, e.g. `dictInUse` add the used rooms to it, then you can test for `dictInUse.Exists(roomNumber)`

Comment: This worked, thanks - I never knew about this